# Copy index from DataFrame to second frame when 'index length mismatch'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df1` (index as a datetime) and `df2` with many columns,different length index.
I need to combine `df1`with `df2`, replacing index in `df2`. As a result presented `df3`.

```py
df1
                      T1
2011-09-01 00:00:00   10
2011-09-01 00:10:00   20
2011-09-01 00:20:00   30  
2011-09-01 00:30:00   40

df2
    T2   T3        
0   1.1  2.0 
1   1.2  3.0
2   1.3  4.0

df3
                      T1   T2  T3
2011-09-01 00:00:00   10  1.1  2.0
2011-09-01 00:10:00   20  1.2  3.0
2011-09-01 00:20:00   30  1.3  4.0
2011-09-01 00:30:00   40  Nan  Nan
```

I wanted to try `concat, join, merge, append` but those doesn't seem to be appropriate.
Using `set_index` resulted in having an error: length mismatch.

I end up trying this:

```py
  df3=pd.DataFrame(df2,index=df1.index,copy=True)
```

I got the desired index, and columns from `df2` but they were empty.

Comment: It's definitely worth reading the docs and really understanding what each one does relative to the other. You'll gain a bit of intuition for when you should use each. Personally, I end up using `concat` more than any of the others.

Comment: I've spent many hours for this "easy" task, reading docs and web pages and...I'm thankful for getting help from you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
In [32]: from pandas import DataFrame, date_range, concat

In [33]: from numpy.random import randn

In [34]: df = DataFrame(randn(5, 1), index=date_range('20010101', periods=5), columns=['A'])

In [35]: df2 = DataFrame(randn(3, 2), columns=list('BC'))

In [36]: concat([df, df2.set_index(df.index[:len(df2)])], axis=1)
Out[36]:
                A      B      C
2001-01-01 -0.043  0.759 -0.125
2001-01-02 -1.377  0.895  0.629
2001-01-03  0.263 -0.007 -0.515
2001-01-04  1.546    NaN    NaN
2001-01-05 -0.657    NaN    NaN
```

You can also do this with `DataFrame.join()` for slightly shorter code:

```
In [7]: df.join(df2.set_index(df.index[:len(df2)]))
Out[7]:
                A      B      C
2001-01-01 -0.607 -0.038  0.593
2001-01-02  0.573  0.399 -0.627
2001-01-03  0.319  0.312 -0.152
2001-01-04 -1.671    NaN    NaN
2001-01-05 -1.589    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: kind of feels like there could be a way to insert via iloc in one go, but I can't think of it.

Comment: Thank you @Philip Cloud. I tried both your answers. For this example all work perfectly but when I introduced this to my files only `df.join` was ok. Using `concat` got 'ValueError: Shape of passed values is (18, 52760), indices imply (18, 52727)'. It's strange because df1 len is 52716 and df2 52555.

Comment: After `df.join` the `df3.index`got 22 more index entries than `df1.index`. Doing some calculation on df1 and df3 I've received 'TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index'.

Comment: I've checked df1 index column and they were some duplicates. After removing, both methods works. Anyway `join` and `concat` doesn't work properly in case there are duplicated index entries...

Comment: If you have duplicate indexes in `df` and then you're resetting the index of `df2` to match that of `df`, then you'll necessarily have duplicates in the `join`ed index. So the extra index entries are expected. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: The duplicated entries in `df3`index occurred 2 times more than in `df1`. Other columns were somehow interpolated.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw out another (hacky) method, this one modifies `df1`:

```
In [11]: df1[df2.columns] = np.nan

In [12]: df1
Out[12]:
                     T1  T2  T3
2011-09-01 00:00:00  10 NaN NaN
           00:10:00  20 NaN NaN
           00:20:00  30 NaN NaN
           00:30:00  40 NaN NaN

In [13]: df1.iloc[:len(df2.index), -len(df2.columns):] = df2.values

In [14]: df1
Out[14]:
                     T1   T2  T3
2011-09-01 00:00:00  10  1.1   2
           00:10:00  20  1.2   3
           00:20:00  30  1.3   4
           00:30:00  40  NaN NaN
```

*Note: This will get tripped up if you have duplicate colnames.*

However, I prefer @PhilipClouds's method.